# Calling a custom method in linq to Entities without AsEnumerable

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

Currently I have some Entity Framework code that looks like this:

```
return _context
           .MyData
           .OrderBy(x => x.Name)
           .Select(x => new CustomObject { Name = x.Name, Description = x.Description });
```

I would like to be able to move out the creation of my `CustomObject` code to a separate function, so something like this:

```
 return _context
           .MyData
           .OrderBy(x => x.Name)
           .Select(x => CustomObjectFactory.Create(x));
```

But when I do this I get the

> Linq to entities does not recognise the method

error. I understand I can just chuck in a call to `AsEnumerable()`:

```
return _context
          .MyData
          .OrderBy(x => x.Name)
          .AsEnumerable()
          .Select(x => CustomObjectFactory.Create(x));
```

But I'd like to know how to do this without the extra `AsEnumerable()` call. I'm pretty sure it involves some kind of complex expression tree.

For bonus points, I'd also be interested in how to do this:

```
 return _context
            .MyData
            .OrderBy(x => x.Name)
            .CreateCustomObject()
```

Comment: If you want to include an extension method in LINQ to Entities, the source parameter (`this` parameter) and return type should set as `IQueryable<T>` so that it can be translated to corresponding SQL statements. Related issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30452426/using-custom-methods-in-linq-to-entities.

Comment: `I'm pretty sure it involves some kind of complex expression tree.` How did you come to that conclusion?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this, because until You call `AsEnumerable` all this code will be translated to database query. Code inside this select is not regular code, but an `expression`, that gets translated to sql statements. Database does not know Your custom methods - it knows only some of methods defined by Your entity framework vendor, with some libraries it is possible to call functions returning primitive types.

After calling `AsEnumerable` results of query are materialized, so You can use regular c# methods.

Comment: You could do some hack implementing `IQueryable` yourself, that would wrap IQueryable.Provider and mess with it, but probably You don't want to do that.

Comment: No, that is not true, you can create your own Expression<Func<>> that does it.

Comment: @Rocklan You can only use `new` and object initializes in Expressions, if You use custom function like `CustomObjectFactory.Create` provider will throw.